# ability to auto play on scroll position in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am on my way to develop my first jQuery plugin.In which I need an animation to auto play on scroll position.I have tried many ideas but nothing worked out.Finally I put the auto play function inside plugin and called in my HTML like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        jQuery.fn.autoplayAnimation();
 });
```

is there any way that I can put document.ready() or window.scroll() inside my plugin and make it working as it is in HTML.
any help will be great full..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to auto assign the event when the page loads right?

why don't you just put this in your plugin file:

```
(function($){

//your plugin code

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        jQuery.fn.autoplayAnimation();
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am really happy to to tell you that now it works really fine.

Comment: I have one more doubt in this issue.actually I forgot to mention that I am passing a variable to my plugin. But when I tried this in your way that variable is always null(because i use the variable inside your code and your code executes before every other).Is there any way to solve this.

Comment: my code (your plugin) executes after document load completes. Can you show an example in your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
function scrollHandler(){
   jQuery.fn.autoplayAnimation();
}
```